# Preserve config files during system update

Tags: macos

I have a custom entry in one of the config files in `/etc`, for example in `/etc/pam.d/sudo`. During each system update, these changes are lost and I have to add them again. Is there a somewhat standardized mechanism or an external tool that is able to preserve my custom changes during an OS upgrade?

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running?

Comment: I am currently running Monterey on an M1 Macbook Air.

Comment: For `sudoers` and `sshd_config` Monterey allows local modifications without overwriting them. Didn't see something similar for `/etc/pam.d` though